# passar valor de um formulário via filter_input()

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário que contém os seguintes campos:

```
 ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="Cadastro[]" value="S"> Sim
    <input type="checkbox" name="Cadastro[]" value="N"> Não
   ....
```

Estou recuperando os valores dos campos usando o filter_input(). Por ex.:

```
$nomeUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"NomeUsuario",FILTER_DEFAULT);
```

No caso dos campos Cadastro e Editar, como são array, como eu faria para pegar os valores como o filter_input e jogar para dentro de uma função?

```
function executar($cadastro){
   ....
}
```

Estou usando dessa forma, mas não estou conseguindo:

```
$cadastro = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,"Cadastro");
```

Ao dar `var_dump($cadastro);`, ele retorna:

> bool(false)

E quando uso o `$_POST["Cadastro"];`, ele me retorna somente o primeiro valor:

```
$cadastro = $_POST["Cadastro"];

function testar($cadastro){
    foreach($cadastro as $teste){
      $valor = $teste."<br>";
    }
  return $valor;
 }
}
echo testar($cadastro); // Retorno S
```

Comment: Na função `filter_input_array` você não passa o nome da variável, mas sim uma lista com as opções de validação. Veja a [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php).

Comment: Certo... então o único jeito é recuperá-las com o $_POST["Cadastro"]?

Comment: Editei meu post....

Comment: Está confuso em muitos aspectos. Você está utilizando o campo `radio`, que implica em você ter apenas um valor selecionado, mas espera um arranjo e define como arranjo no HTML. O usuário pode ou não selecionar mais de uma opção? E na função `testar` você está atualizando o valor da variável `$valor`, então obviamente que apenas o último valor do arranjo será exibido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver com o a variável global $_POST. Criei uma variável $valor com valor nulo antes do laço e concatenei a variável dentro do laço. Segue abaixo:

```
$cadastro = $_POST["Cadastro"];

function testar($cadastro){
    $valor = "";
    foreach($cadastro as $teste){
      $valor .= $teste."<br>";
    }
  return $valor;
 }
}
echo testar($cadastro);
```

Comment: Mas neste caso você não está filtrando os valores. Qual era exatamente o objetivo da pergunta?